# Flexible diagonal line plot in R

Tags: r, plot, line, diagonal

How can we plot diagonal across (from bottom-left-hand corner to top
right-hand corner),
at any given coordinate ranges?

For example

```
> plot(c(-2,3), c(-1,5), type = "n", xlab="x", ylab="y", asp = 1)
```

or

```
> plot(c(0,1000), c(0,334), type = "n", xlab="x", ylab="y", asp = 1)
```

I tried abline with the following but failed:

```
> abline(0,1,col="red")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The limits of the current plot area are in `par()$usr`.

```
lines( par()$usr[1:2], par()$usr[3:4] )
```